# What's wrong with triggering mouseup within a drag?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, mouseevent

I'm trying to disable jquery drag when I reach the edge of the container (constraints to the x-axis). [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/ppbykecw/) the code:

```
var draggable = $("#drag-draggable");
var draggableWidth = draggable.width();
var draggableParentWidth = $('#drag-wrapper').width();
draggable.draggable({
  axis: "x",
  containment: "parent",
  drag: function (e, ui) {
    if ((draggableRight = ui.position.left + draggableWidth) == draggableParentWidth) {
      draggable.trigger('mouseup');
      console.log("finished");
    }
  }
});
```

The fact is: when I reach the edge (left), the `mouseup` is triggered, but it thrown an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null(…)`

Which stop the drag, resulting not complete (I can see some pixels to the left of the red box).

Why am I wrong?

Comment: @prasad: what? Not sure what you mean. But the problem is still there.. (if you move the move slower against the left). Try!

Comment: It looks like the fix you are looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/ppbykecw/5/  I'm not just sure what exact behaviour you are expecting?!

Comment: It looks it works well! Why anyway? Bug? If you write the answer, you will get +1!

Comment: I have no idea what's going on internally regarding jQuery UI draggable, What i see is that drag event handler is fired before the position element is set and to stop dragging behaviour, you can call `e.preventDefault()` (or `return false;`). It is still better than firing other mouse event which still i don't know how it is internally handled by this plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/u859ygpy/#&togetherjs=Prp4BKkvsU):

JS:

```
var draggable = $("#drag-draggable");
var draggableWidth = draggable.width();
var draggableParentWidth = $('#drag-wrapper').width();
draggable.draggable({
  axis: "x",
  containment: "parent",
  drag: function (e, ui) {
  var draggableRight = draggable.position().left + draggableWidth;
    if (draggableRight >= draggableParentWidth) {
    e.preventDefault();
      draggable.trigger('mouseup');
      console.log("finished");
      //e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
});

draggable.on('mouseup',function(){
console.log('hit');
});
```